# tenho um coluna no meu DF que contem cidades com acentos e preciso remover os acentos de todas as cidades

Tags: python

Tenho uma coluna dentro de um DF com nome de cidade e todas estão com acento, preciso remover os acentos dessas cidades para fazer um merge com dados de outra tabela usando essas cidades como referencia.

Answer (score -1):

Frequentemente preciso resolver o mesmo problema que você descreveu.
Costumo usar a "unidecode".
Link: https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Segue um exemplo que pode usar com o seu data frame:

```
#Digite Para instalar via pip no terminal
#pip install Unidecode
import unidecode as uni

def tira_acentos(nome):
    txt = uni.unidecode(str(nome))
    return txt
# Aqui voce usa o seu df - A nova coluna criada nao tera os acentos
df['nomes_sem_acentos'] = df['nome_da_coluna_inicial'].apply(tira_acentos)
```